# How to export xlsx using apache poi more than 10k data in java and oracle rest data service

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-poi

How do I export xlsx using apache poi? I have more than 10k data in java and oracle rest data service. I have exported it the data is 32k++ but only print 10k data:

```
public ByteArrayInputStream exportExcell (String formcode, String fitur, String payload,Optional<String> state, Optional<String> id, Optional<String> sort, Optional<String> sortBy) throws IOException
    {
        try(
            // SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(-1);
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        )
        {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");
            Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

            .....


            Document data = this.ordsService.query(form.getString("database"), queryData, countQuery);

            int kolom = 0;
            for (Document d : fm)
            {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(kolom);
                cell.setCellValue(d.getString("title"));
                kolom++;
            }

            int baris = 1;
            for (Document d : (List<Document>) data.get("data"))
            {
                row = sheet.createRow(baris);
                int kolomData = 0;
                for (String s : d.keySet())
                {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(kolomData);
                    cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(d.get(s)));
                    kolomData++;
                }
                baris++;
            }
            workbook.write(out);
            
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to [Microsoft Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), Excel workbooks are limited to 1,048,576 rows (most recent MSOffice version). However, your data seem to be far less than that, so what is your problem **exactly**? Do you get an error (message) or just not enough data into a workbook?

Comment: Hint for debugging: Determine what is biggest `baris` you get. And if that is not the expected, determine what `data.get("data").size()` is. If that is not the expected, `this.ordsService.query(form.getString("database"), queryData, countQuery);` does not return what you are expecting.

Comment: i have 32k data but when i export into excel only show 10k data using apache poi

Comment: i didnt got any error message